# Using both oracle db and access for one gridview

Tags: asp.net

I would like to add some functionality to a gridview I have. Essentially I just want to do something similar to AutoGenerateInsert button that asp.net 2.0 does. I want the fields to push data to an AccessDataSource. The trick here though is that I want to verify some fields against an Oracle DB and even auto-populate other fields to what a user has input for a field.. As an example, my Oracle DB has personal information such as names, ages, etc. If the web-app user types in a valid name in a 'Name' field, then the field should be validated and other personal info should be auto-populated. Once all the fields are have been entered then the 'Add' button is clicked and that new record on the gridview inserts the data to an Access DB.

Any links or hints out there for accomplishing something like this?

Thanks!
-doddy

Comment: Do you just need to do client-side validation against the other data source?  (For example, when the user enters a name you make an AJAX call to a separate service entirely to check the name and get data.)  Or does the object itself have two separate data sources?  (In which case you'd probably want to abstract the two data sources behind a repository for the object and the UI would just bind to the object.)

Comment: Right, good question. It would indeed be client side validation. The idea would be once the user has entered the text and clicked 'return key' or possibly tab over to next field then a post back occurs where the check against the Oracle DB is done to validate the entered text. If valid, then auto-populate some other fields, if not, an error message appears saying something like "text entered is not valid". So ya each object itself simply looks at one DB. Once all the fields are entered (and have been validated) then the new record updates Access DB with all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should store two connectionstring in web.config in aap tag 
when you want to validate fields get connectionstring[0] and when you want to save field get connectionstring[1]  i assume that you know how to load and save data 
theres nothing complex in it.here is example

```
<appSettings>
<add key="dbConnection1" value="Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;     Initial Catalog=dbname;Data Source=servername"/>
<add key="dbConnection2" value="Datasource=servername;    Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=dbuser;Password=dbpassword" />
</appSettings>
```

now in code behind

```
public string GetconnectionString1()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconnection1"];
    }

public string GetconnectionString2()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbconnection2"];
    }
```

Comment: Interesting. I was thinking of this in a different way than you. I was thinking along the lines of creating a custom TemplateField that binds the fields to an SQLdatasource for validating the data and would be used for a SelectCommand with this Oracle DB. Once the new record is validated and able to be used then it would use another datasource (AccessDataSource) which would be used with an InsertCommand. The code behind I was thinking just to use with the OnRowCreated for the GridView.

Of course the connection strings need to be specified in code behind.

Comment: Ahh.. ran out of characters.. So basically I was wondering if it is possible to have a gridview that uses multiple datasources. Each being a different type than the other..